# Suricata luajit compilation error

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, lua, archlinux, luajit

I'm currently trying to compile suricata (http://suricata-ids.org/) with luajit support on my arch linux distribution with these commands:

```
./configure --enable-luajit --with-libpcap-includes=/usr/local/pfring/include \
--with-libpcap-libraries=/usr/local/pfring/lib --with-libnss-libraries=/usr/lib \ 
--with-libnss-includes=/usr/include/nss/ --with-libnspr-libraries=/usr/lib \
--with-libnspr-includes=/usr/include/nspr \
--with-libluajit-includes=/usr/local/include/luajit-2.0/ \
--with-libluajit-libraries=/usr/lib/
```

then:

```
make
```

but I get the following errors when I make the project:

```
detect-luajit.o: In function `LuaDumpStack':
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to `lua_tonumberx'
detect-luajit.o: In function `DetectLuajitMatchBuffer':
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0x5d6): undefined reference to `lua_getglobal'
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0x6b9): undefined reference to `lua_pcallk'
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0x7d5): undefined reference to `lua_tonumberx'
detect-luajit.o: In function `DetectLuajitMatch':
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0xaac): undefined reference to `lua_getglobal'
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0xde4): undefined reference to `lua_pcallk'
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0xf00): undefined reference to `lua_tonumberx'
detect-luajit.o: In function `DetectLuajitThreadInit':
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0x1864): undefined reference to `lua_pcallk'
detect-luajit.o: In function `DetectLuaSetupPrime':
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0x1fe7): undefined reference to `lua_pcallk'
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0x2167): undefined reference to `lua_getglobal'
detect-luajit.c:(.text+0x24bf): undefined reference to `lua_pcallk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [suricata] Error 1
```

I first though it was an issue coming from the lua version. So I tried to install both the lua 5.1.5 and 5.2.2, remaking the library and symbolic links as well, and nothing worked.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Those functions are specific to Lua 5.2, while LuaJIT only implements Lua 5.1.

Comment: Thanks for this information. But it compiled fine on my ubuntu VM with the same program version of Lua/LuaJit as those on my arch linux. So there must be a solution, but I can't find it =/

Answer (score 1):

In Debian and Ubuntu, the library files are installed into /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. If arch does the same, your configure line should include: --with-libluajit-libraries=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/